# Period of a pseudo-random sequence generated using an LFSR

Tags: algorithm-analysis, pseudo-random-generators, random-number-generator

I was trying to generate maximal length pseudo random sequence using an linear feedback shift register ([LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR)).
I have read from many sources that the length of the pseudo random sequence generated from the LFSR would be maximum if and only if the corresponding feedback polynomial is primitive.

I have tried to generate the pseudo random sequence for the primitive polynomial (4,1,0) (corresponding to polynomial $x^4 + x + 1$) by tapping at bits 4 and 1, and it has resulted in a sequence with a period of $2^4$ - 1 = 15. Similarly I have tried primitive polynomial given by (3, 1, 0) (corresponding to polynomial $x^3 + x + 1$) by tapping at bits 3 and 1 and it has resulted in a sequence of period $2^3$ - 1 = 7.

When I tried to apply this same logic to the primitive polynomial (5, 2, 0) (corresponding to polynomial $x^5 + x^2 + 1$) it yields a sequence with period 15. While it should have yielded a sequence with period 2^5 -1 = 31. Following is the circuit diagram for (5, 2, 0)

[image: (5, 2, 0) LFSR]

1) What is the exact procedure to convert the given polynomial into a maximal length LFSR?

2) How do I determine the correct tap bits for a given polynomial?

Comment: I think your implementation may be wrong. See http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1123/157

Answer (score 3):

The LFSR that you give is really of length $4$ rather than $5$, since $b_1$ never gets used. The correct way to implement a "Fibonacci" LFSR is explained in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register): $b_1$ should be the *leftmost* bit rather than the *rightmost* bit.

There is also an alternative kind of LFSR knows as a "Galois" LFSR, also described in Wikipedia, which is dual to a Fibonacci LFSR: at each point, the contents of the register is shifted, and if the bit which is shifted out is 1, then a mask is XORed to the contents. In both types of LFSR, the resulting sequence has maximum period iff the feedback polynomial is primitive.

---

The polynomials that you give as examples are known as *trinomials*, polynomials with three non-zero monomials. Not all trinomials are primitive. There are algorithms for deciding whether a trinomial, or any other polynomial, is primitive. As far as I know, there is no explicit construction of primitive polynomials.

How do we test whether a given polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ is primitive? The first step is verifying that it is irreducible. The second step verifies that $x^{(2^n-1)/p} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{P}$ for every prime divisor $p$ of $2^n-1$ – this step requires factoring $2^n-1$. A list of primitive polynomials can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register#Some_polynomials_for_maximal_LFSRs).

Comment: I totally agree with you that not all tri-nomials are primitive polynomials. However, (3,1,0), (4, 1, 0), (5,2,0) are all primitive polynomials.

Comment: If the resulting sequence has period 15 then $(5,2,0)$ isn't primitive, by definition. That said, $(5,2,0)$ appears on the list of primitive polynomials linked to on Wikipedia, so perhaps your code has a bug.

Comment: Finally I understand your question and can answer it (see my updated answer).

Comment: Here is a Matlab code snippet which tells that (5,2,0) is primitive. >> poly3 = primpoly(5)
 
Primitive polynomial(s) = 
 
D^5+D^2+1

poly3 =

    37

>> dec2bin(poly3)

ans =

100101

>>

Comment: Thanks for that update @Yuval Filmus. I still have some doubts on this. My polynomial is (5,2,0) that will translate to $x^5+x^2+x^0$=$x^5+x^2+1$. This sequence, being a primitive polynomial should have a length of $2^5 - 1 = 31$. That means that this shift register should traverse through 31 states before repeating the state again. Now that we need to represent 31 states, we need 5 bits ($2^5$ -1) . That means my register would have bits b5, b4, b3, b2 and b1 (each represents a bit). Could you please elaborate on how you say that this diagram represents shift register of length 4?

Comment: You can extend your register to length 100 by adding $b_0,b_{-1},\ldots$, and nothing would change in its operation. What matters is the rightmost tap.